# Visual Studio Code - Run task outside of the devcontainer

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, vscode-devcontainer

I want to know if it is possible to run a vscode task outside the current devcontainer, I ask this because I work inside a node 16 container angular project with cordova, and one of my tasks would be to open the cordova project with android studio, like so:

```sh
studio ./cordova/platforms/android
```

But when I try to run it as an npm script it tells me that studio is not a known command because he is running the command inside the conatiner where there's no android studio.

Anybody knows if this is possible? Is there a known workaround to this maybe?